# INTEGRATING AZURE AD WITH SSRS IN AZURE VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-active-directory, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to have azure authentication with ssrs reports in azure vm and database on prem.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SSRS [does not support Azure AD authentication](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/modernizing-ssrs-and-a-step-by-step-guide-to-bringing/ba-p/2483050).

A possible alternative is to map your Azure AD identities to Windows authentication, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-oauth-ssrs).

Comment: We donot have windows active directory also in vm, what can be the possible authentication possible